# How to add debug/set -x is bash script as option for getopts

Tags: bash, debugging, sh, getopts

I want to pass the debug facility as an user-input in a bash script. Let's take the below code as a sample script.

```
#!/bin/bash

usage() { echo "Usage: $0 [-d <Integer>] [-m <String>]" 1>&2; exit 1; }
while getopts "hld:p:" o; do
    case "${o}" in
        d)
            d=${OPTARG}
            [[ $d =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || usage
            ;;
        p)
            p=${OPTARG}
            [[ $p =~ [a-zA-Z] ]] || usage
            ;;
        l) # to enable logging/debug -- set -x
            l=${OPTARG}
            ;;
        h|*)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))
if [ -z "${d}" ] || [ -z "${m}" ]; then
    usage
fi
echo "d = ${d}"
echo "m = ${m}"
```

How can I add it in this?

Comment: How do you expect this  to work? if your script had already started executing?

Comment: @Inian , Not after it has started executing, but when it is called... the user will call it as [./script.sh -d 123 -m test -l ] to initialize the script with debug on.

Comment: Remove `# to enable logging/debug -- ` from your script?

Comment: @Cyrus that is to show the option that I want to use to enable the debug function or call set -x. But I don't know how to do that as a user-input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getops argument, help message and case statement are not consistent:

- getops argument `d:h:p:`, specifies options `-d` `-h` and `-p` (also `h:` means `-h` requires an argument)
- help message, documents options `-d` and `-m`
- case statement, handles options `-d` `-p` `-l` and `-h` ..

Adding `l` in getopts argument and removing `:` after using `h`

```
while getopts "d:hlp:" o; do
case "${o}" in
...
    l)  set -x
        ;;
...
    esac
done
```

Comment: this seems to work, but when I use it with other options and if one of them calls a function, the debug doesn't work. So in almost all cases, the '-l' has to be the first option given, otherwise it doesn't work. Any workaround for that?

Comment: there is no reason it doesn't work except if option is after a non-option parameter or an argument after an option not declared with a `:`, for example `getopts z` without `:`, and called `script.sh -z abc` here `abc` is taken as script first argument `$1` (not argument for option) so getopts stops reading options.

Comment: If the first argument calls a function (with exit command in it), the script goes for the function, completes and exits and never reaches to the second argument to enable 'set -x'. I'm getting results in my tests in lab. Otherwise it works fine.